# Error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, makefile, openmp, clion

When I run my Makefile, it gives me the following error:

`E:/Cygwin/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

It doesn't specify which library is missing?

This is my Makefile:

```
CC:= E:\Cygwin\bin\gcc.exe
CXX:= E:\Cygwin\bin\g++.exe
CFLAGS=-O3 -fopenmp -std=c99
CXXFLAGS=-O3 -fopenmp

all: daxpy

daxpy: daxpy.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o daxpy daxpy.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECS) *.o
```

I had to specify my compiler path, because otherwise it couldn't find it.

(It gave me the error `make: g++: No such file or directory` until I changed it this way)

Does anyone have any ideas? It seems to not be able to find certain things, because I also get an `undefined reference to 'omp_get_wtime'` error when I run my `main` function.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using Makefiles over a build system like CMake? CMake will generate Makefiles more systematically for you.

Comment: Similar side note: Unless you need Cygwin's POSIX compatibility layer, it's usually an unnecessary complication vs  a modern mingw distribution like [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/4581301).

Comment: This Makefile was already prepared for us students. I created a CMakeLists.txt and built it with Cygwin, but when I build it in CLion, the same error occurs (undefined reference to...)

Comment: I am having the same issue here, but it's a Delphi project: No Cygwin, no cmake, no makefile, no c++